# Create new column based on end of a string with different lengths in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, multiple-columns

Dataframe

```
   description               total      average      number
0 NFL football (white) L     49693        66       1007
1 NFL football (white) XL    79682        74       1198
2 NFL football (white) XS    84943        81       3792
3 NFL football (white) S     78371        73       3974
4 NFL football (blue) L      99482        92       3978
5 NFL football (blue) M      32192        51       3135
6 NFL football (blue XL      75343        71       2879
7 NFL football (red) XXL     84391        79       1192
8 NFL football (red) XS      34727        57       992
9 NFL football (red) L       44993        63       1562
```

What I would like to do is create a new column containing the size (e.g. L, Xl, XXL) from the end of the string in the `'description'` column.

Desired output:

```
   description               total      average      number  size
0 NFL football (white) L      49693        66       1007       L
1 NFL football (white) XL    79682        74       1198       XL
2 NFL football (white) XS    84943        81       3792       XS
3 NFL football (white) S     78371        73       3974       S
4 NFL football (blue) L      99482        92       3978       L
5 NFL football (blue) M      32192        51       3135       M
6 NFL football (blue XL      75343        71       2879       XL
7 NFL football (red) XXL     84391        79       1192       XXL
8 NFL football (red) XS      34727        57       992        XS
9 NFL football (red) L       44993        63       1562       L
```

Comment: `df['size'] = df['description'].str.split().str[-1]`

Comment: Does it  work? `df['new_column'] = df['description'].str.split()[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

`df['size'] = df['description'].str.split().str[-1]` – Andreas 8 mins ago

Thank you! this did perfectly, much appreciated.